# Error message on certain text inputs using Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm pretty new to python and I'm currently working on an assignment to implement a movie recommendation system. I have a .csv file that contains various descriptions of a given movie's attribute. I ask the user for a movie title and then the system returns similar movies.

The dataset is named movie_dataset.csv from this folder on GitHub: https://github.com/codeheroku/Introduction-to-Machine-Learning/tree/master/Building%20a%20Movie%20Recommendation%20Engine

The problem I am encountering is that when I ask the user to enter a movie title, the program only works for certain titles.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
#helper functions#
def get_title_from_index(index):
    return df[df.index == index]["title"].values[0]

def get_index_from_title(title):
    return df[df.title == title]["index"].values[0]

df = pd.read_csv("movie_dataset.csv")
#print (df.columns)

features = ['keywords','cast','genres','director']
for feature in features:
    df[feature] = df[feature].fillna('')

def combine_features(row):
    return row['keywords'] +" "+ row['cast'] +" "+ row['genres'] +" "+ row['director']

df["combine_features"] = df.apply(combine_features, axis=1)
#print (df["combine_features"].head())

cv = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(df["combine_features"])

#MTitle = input("Type in a movie title: ")
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix)
movie_user_likes = 'Avatar'#MTitle

movie_index = get_index_from_title(movie_user_likes)

similar_movies = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[movie_index]))
sorted_similar_movies = sorted(similar_movies, key= lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

i = 0
for movie in sorted_similar_movies:
    print (get_title_from_index(movie[0]))
    i=i+1
    if i>10:
        break
```

When I enter "Batman" the program runs fine. But when I run "Harry Potter" I get:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-687ddb420709> in <module>
     30 movie_user_likes = MTitle
     31 
---> 32 movie_index = get_index_from_title(movie_user_likes)
     33 
     34 similar_movies = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[movie_index]))

<ipython-input-51-687ddb420709> in get_index_from_title(title)
     8 
     9 def get_index_from_title(title):
---> 10         return df[df.title == title]["index"].values[0]
     11 
     12 df = pd.read_csv("movie_dataset.csv")

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's simply no entry in the data base for the movie "Harry Potter"
You should add some testing for these cases such as:

```
def get_index_from_title(title):
    try:
        return df[df.title == title]["index"].values[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Then of course in the calling code you'll have to test if you got a `None` from the function and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, but I ran a search in the database with excel for "harry potter" and it is listed twice.

Comment: @James No. You need an exact match. There's not a single entry for "Harry Potter". There's "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince" and others, but no "Harry Potter"

Comment: @James BTW, if you need the input "Harry Potter" to match "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince", there are ways you can do this. The general term might be fuzzy text matching. Or you can simply make a search among the titles to find a title that contains the query as a sub-string for example. You can use a text search engine such as Whoosh to make it in less than linear time: https://pypi.org/project/Whoosh/